# Convert nested loops according to Java 8 nested loops

Tags: java-8

Found difficulty to change this code according to java8 lambda expression.
The code removes student object which have same name and add that object into a single entry.

```
public List<Student> removeDuplicates(List<Student> studentList)

{

    List<Student> newStudentList=new ArrayList<Student>();
    List<String> studentNames= new ArrayList<String>();
    studentList.stream().forEach(e->studentNames.add(e.getName()));
    List<String> studentNameList= new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Student student: studentList) {
            int count=0;
            for (String sname: studentNames)
            {
                if(student.getName().equals(sname)){
                    count++;
                    }
                    else{
                        count=0;
                    }
                    if(count==1)
                    {   if(!studentNameList.contains(student.getName())){
                        studentNameList.add(student.getName());
                        newStudentList.add(student);
                    }
                    }
                }

            }
}
```

Comment: That code looks horrible. Maybe you try to find a clean pre-Java 8 solution first, before trying to adapt it to new Java features…

Comment: but this doesn't work------------    studentList.stream().forEach(e -> {
   studentNames.stream().filter(f -> e.getName().equals(f));
  });

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    public Stream<Student> removeDuplicates(List<Student> studentList) {
    return studentList
            .stream()
            .collect(
                    Collectors.toMap(Student::getName, s -> s,
                            (fst, snd) -> fst)).values().stream();
}
```

Comment: Thank you,This is very useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) streams.

```
public List<Student> removeDuplicates(List<Student> studentList) {
    return studentList.stream()
                      .map(Student::getName)
                      .distinct()
                      .map(x -> studentList.stream()
                                           .filter(y -> y.getName().equals(x))
                                           .findFirst()
                                           .get())
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Thank you,This is solution is most useful.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you must end up with a `List`, otherwise you would have chosen to use a `Set` which by definition is a unique collection. A `Set` could still be part of the solution, however, doing something like

```
Set<String> tempUniqueValues = new HashSet<>();
List<String> listWithoutDupes = myList.stream()
        .filter(tempUniqueValues::add)          // filters out non-unique values
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```